# Changing Text Color of Specific PreferenceScreen in PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, layout, textview, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

So currently I have a PreferenceFragment with a couple of preferences in there like so:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="menu"
        android:key="menu">

        <PreferenceScreen
            android:title="pref1"
            android:key="pref1" />

        <PreferenceScreen
            android:title="pref2"
            android:key="pref2" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

If I want to change the color of "pref2" so that it can be red, how would I do it?  I've looked at a couple of different solutions.  One of them was to create it's own layout.  So I tried that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="pref2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And it doesn't work because the margin is off, the height is wrapped instead of matching parent, and the size seems off as well.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone was wondering, the hacky solution I found was to create a RelativeLayout and hardcode in the textsize, margin, and height of the TextView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="pref2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/menu_sign_out_text"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```